# How to remove unnecessary casting with Ramda and Typescript

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

Consider

```
const darkPalette = [
  '#255dbd',
  '#2c6bd7',
  '#5386e2',
  '#7ea5e9',
  '#49bbdb',
  '#56d6f9',
  '#89e2fa',
  '#aaeafc',
  '#00a690',
  '#10bda4',
  '#6ad8c8',
  '#9de4da',
  '#9dc53b',
  '#bae050',
  '#dcf0a3',
  '#eaf6c8',
]

const transposePalette = compose(flatten, transpose, splitEvery(4))

const transposedDarkPalette = transposePalette(darkPalette)
```

When i receive the result of `transposedDarkPalette` the compiler complains:

`Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
          Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'`

I can fix this by doing

```
const transposedDarkPalette = (transposePalette(darkPalette) as unknown) as string[]
```

but it's kind of ugly and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: I'm afraid there are still many problems combining Typescript with Ramda.  It doesn't seem capable of easily handling the sorts of functions generated by `compose` or `pipe`.  I don't have any good solutions for this.

Comment: Well, why use Typescript (type safety at compile time) with Ramda (HOFs & Functional Composition) when you can use [ReasonML](https://reasonml.github.io/) - Functional, Typed, compiled to JS and have more of both features provided?

Answer (score 2):

The type inference of TS doesn't work well enough to bring the correct types through `compose`, as the commenters already stated.

One solution is so specify the generics of `compose` manually:

```
const transposePalette = compose<string[], unknown, unknown, string[]>(flatten, transpose, splitEvery(4))
```

The first generic is the input parameter, the last generic the output parameter. To keep the declaration short, the interim types are omitted.