# Typescript generic argument to const value

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to have a const value that takes generic argument?

For this code

```js
import * as R from 'ramda';

enum ApiActionType {
  requested,
  completed,
  failed,
  cancelled,
}

type ApiActionTypeKeys = keyof typeof ApiActionType;

enum ChangedActionType {
  changed,
}

type ChangedActionTypeKeys = keyof typeof ChangedActionType;

const getActionType = <TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys extends string>(
  keys: TActionTypeKeys[]
) => (
  prefix: TPrefix
): Record<TActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys]> => {
  return R.pipe(
    R.map(k => [k, [prefix, k]] as [TActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys]]),
    R.fromPairs as () => Record<TActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys]>
  )(keys);
}

// const createApiActionType: <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => Record<"requested" | "completed" | "failed" | "cancelled", [TPrefix, "requested" | "completed" | "failed" | "cancelled"]>
const createApiActionType = <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => getActionType<TPrefix, ApiActionTypeKeys>(R.keys(ApiActionType))(prefix)
// const createChangedctionType: <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => Record<"changed", [TPrefix, "changed"]>
const createChangedctionType = <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => getActionType<TPrefix, ChangedActionTypeKeys>(R.keys(ChangedActionType))(prefix)
```

Is it possible to simplify the last two lines to below without lost generic argument to the resulting function? i.e. preserve the `TPrefix` generic argument instead of become a non-generic function with `unknown` prefix type

```js
// const createApiActionType: (prefix: unknown) => Record<"requested" | "completed" | "failed" | "cancelled", [unknown, "requested" | "completed" | "failed" | "cancelled"]>
const createApiActionType = getActionType(R.keys(ApiActionType))
// const createChangedctionType: (prefix: unknown) => Record<"changed", [unknown, "changed"]>
const createChangedctionType = getActionType(R.keys(ChangedActionType))
```

Comment: Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363310/how-to-remove-unnecessary-casting-with-ramda-and-typescript. Doubt it's possible untli variadic types land in Typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a curried `getActionType` function declaration

```
declare const getActionType: <TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys extends string>(
  keys: TActionTypeKeys[]
) => (
    prefix: TPrefix
  ) => Record<TActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys]>
```

, the generic type parameter `TPrefix` is not preserved for the inner function, but instead instantiated with a [default `unknown`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown) type. TS looks for a code location to infer its type argument in the outer function signature of `getActionType` and falls back to `unknown`, because `TPrefix` is unused here. 
[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=64&pln=24&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDgSxgYwC4IPYgCoE87BQDeAsAFBRQBOwAjmMAM6rAAmANOZchhHADbAWHLlABmAQwSCRFKMgkhkwfjM5kAvuXKp8heEjSYcegNLBcjKAF4oAawsYxUXQSexEKdFjwEA3NpkoJBQAMIAFooA5mxexr6EpHLIkSAxslpkOnphqelxPmYWVrYOuO6uwO4R0bFGhf6BrMDI-BI08ljMUDGoBSYEAFxQADzYAAo0YggAHuxQ2P0J5pZQwDMsIKxWzFQIaQB8ABSiZYzDi-UDwCuMANoAuuQAlDYHUCdylHBTsxeTwGmM1Er2s7wASi0MFRWGMlkVLPM7hNfnMFvCCLcHgcmi02h0eCBuilaqwMTdisMamk6t5rrdHrjWu1CITuhJPFdlpSPIY6dzLIyyAB6YUfH6Av5QMAgOwgDAAdxAoIhUJhIwM5NuSJlcsVIHm1PyXIRjGx5DZqHkNAkLCNbBNBBsPSE5KOHL58VNzyAA):

```
declare const apiActionTypeKeys: ApiActionTypeKeys[]

// (prefix: unknown) => Record<ApiActionTypeKeys, [unknown, ChangedActionTypeKeys]>
const createChangedctionType = getActionType(apiActionTypeKeys)
```

We can fix that by defining `TPrefix` on the inner function.

```
declare const getActionType: <TActionTypeKeys extends string>(
    keys: TActionTypeKeys[]
) => <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => Record<TActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, TActionTypeKeys]>
```

And test it:

```
declare const apiActionTypeKeys: ApiActionTypeKeys[]
declare const changedActionTypeKeys: ChangedActionTypeKeys[]

// <TPrefix>(prefix: TPrefix) => Record<ApiActionTypeKeys, [TPrefix, ApiActionTypeKeys]>
const createApiActionType = getActionType(apiActionTypeKeys)

// "requested" | "completed" | "failed" | "cancelled"
const result = createApiActionType("fooPrefix").cancelled[1]
```

[Full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=58&pln=20&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggDgSxgYwC4IPYgCoE87BQDeAsAFBSVQBOwAjmMAM6rAAmANOVVMhhHAA2wVp25UAZgEMEwsRSrIpIZMEFyuZAL7lyqfIXhI0mHAYDSwXEygBeKAGsrGCVH0EXsRCnRY8BAG5dMlBIKABhAAtlAHN2H1N-QlIFSmRokDi2ch0yPQMIjKyEvwsrG3snXE93YE8o2PiTUsDgtmBkQSlaXiwWKDjUErMCAC4oAB5sYaTLayhgAA9WEDYbFmoETIA+AApxSiqmcenmkeA5pgBtAF1yAEo7bcnsAAVaCQRFvbgPr5P3sBPotHrZngAlDoYahsKYzMrWDhQK5vP6LJGnXznS43bZtDpdHp8ED9KTeM6zcrjIzwgiXW7kdqdbqEYn9dKNNi0i5Uwqc7n0u55MgAehFL0BwJ+aIBaNBEKhMImNIpCKYSJRkq+SJVWMp1lx5DZqF4tCkrF1iQK9kG3N2ZOMerV92CYolaOlQP+UFRXpBTygkL4SoamSaTrp5Q1vuBSNDxVVkYNeLIxtNwHNwHj7EThBtIjtHLDXNzlxdwrdACJaAxmKJK1AAD5QSt8ATCetNlvSWTsBvN1vKVTqPtGvom2gVdOZy0tYC7SsSDAYLWLSv3AB0ShUajkVwAjELgkA)

Hope, it helps!